# Stripe negative invoice amount

Tags: stripe-payments

I am using stripe for subscribing customers to a monthly plan. Halfway through the customer may decrease the plan quantity. So, in the upcoming invoice will sometimes be negative.

Does invoice line with negative amount means the customer will be refunded those amount into their card?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, negative invoice amounts act as credits to the customer which are offset against the customers balance for subsequent invoices

https://support.stripe.com/questions/handling-subscription-changes
https://stripe.com/docs/subscriptions/guide#upgrading-or-downgrading-plans

Comment: It's my understanding that the answer to this question is no, actually. Stripe seems to simply create a negative invoice for the subscription but does attempt to refund the payment source. As far as I am aware you can only do that by created a refund associated with a particular charge.

Comment: Refund is different than a "stripe credit". Stripe indeed adds credit to the user so he can use it in future payments, but it doesn't transfer it back to the customer (refund)